# fancybox link not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

I tried getting the latest versions and editing the links etc. But I'm kind of lost I guess. This project has been going on for months and it has lots of plugins and scripts on it now though it's not ideal. But I've used fancybox in many projects, never had an issue before.

So here's the link that doesn't work on IE8:
http://www.africanbushcamps.com/abc/image-galleries/safari-pictures/
Here you click on a gallery image and it should open up the gallery in a fancybox iframe.

Would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have a javascript error before you attach fancybox to the specified selectors. The script hangs there, hence the fancyboxes not firing.

Comment: Thank you. Appereantly a new plugin they installed had an error. Now that's fixed and it looks like it says jquery itself has an error? Am I right? Am I on the right track? I haven't personally done IE debugging before.

Comment: There's a bunch of plugins in this page... You should try to desactivate them all and reactivate one by one to find the culprit. The error is not in jQuery itself, IE reports the error in jQuery because it's called by another script.